# Multiple conditions if least minimum are met then print PYTHON

Tags: python

-need your help, I have 10 conditions where if any 5 conditions are true then function will
-shortlist those 5 and from that if any 3 conditions are true then function will validate:

```
con1 = check(df)
con2 = check2(df)
con3 = check3(df)
con4 = check4(df)
con5 = check5(df)
if ([con1 or con2 or con3 or con4 or con5]) == True:
    then check if atleast 3 conditions are True: 
       if true:
           print(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

For checking whether at least 3 conditions are true, you can do:

```py
if sum([cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4, cond5]) >= 3:
```

The `sum()` function will treat `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`.

This assumes that all of the conditions are boolean values. See the comments for handling things like `None`.

Comment: Hi Thank you I am getting this error for doing as you advised:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: In fact it is guaranteed that `True==1` and `False==0`; `issubclass(bool, int)` is true.

Comment: Some of your condition functions are returning `None`. Without seeing the contents of the check functions, there's not much I can do.

Comment: def check(df):
    if df.c.tail(1).values > df.EMA.tail(1).values:
        print(symbol +' PRICE ABOVE EMA')
        return True

def check2(df):
    if df.c.tail(1).values > df.SMA.tail(1).values:
        print(symbol + ' PRICE ABOVE SMA')
        return True

def check3(df):
    if df.RSI.tail(1).values < 40:
        print(symbol + ' RSI BELOW 40')
        return True

Comment: @user18719324 you can fix that by using `bool(cond1)` etc. because `bool(None)` is `False`.

Comment: Or, use `sum(map(lambda x: bool(x), [cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4, cond5]))`.

Comment: @user18719324 or you could fix your functions so they always return something even if the `if` fails.  If you don't have an explicit `return` for every code path a function will return `None`.